# Crop rectangle from image and print and save it

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rectangles

I want to draw a rectangle inside an image (imageToCrop), which is in a `Canvas`, and print that cropped rectangle beside the image.
Then I need to save it to a new file.
I draw a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` on my image and this work.
Here is my code to crop the rectangle and print it to another image (croppedImage) :

```
croppedImage.Width = selectionBox.Width;  
croppedImage.Height = selectionBox.Height;  
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)imageToCrop.Source, new Int32Rect(Convert.ToInt32(Canvas.GetLeft(selectionBox)), Convert.ToInt32(Canvas.GetTop(selectionBox)), Convert.ToInt32(selectionBox.Width), Convert.ToInt32(selectionBox.Height)));
croppedImage.Source = cb;
```

The problem is that I get in the other image a new image witch have the good sizes, Height and Width of the drawn rectangle, but it's an unyform color, not related to the drawn rectangle...
I don't understand why ?

Comment: Did you check if the Int32Rect values match your expectation? Assign it to a local variable and set a breakpoint.

Comment: Seems correct, I have a good X and Y, and the height and width are good too

Comment: As a test, hard-code the x, y, width, and height parameters in the `CroppedBitmap` constructor.

Comment: Tried this, doing same thing.

Comment: Finally it worked when I switched the source to a bitmap file (it was a jpeg) and I had to do some adjustments on the width and height to adapt to pixelheight/width